# calculate sql percentage of column a grouped by column b

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My data is as follows:

### name | color

```
joe | red  
joe | red
tom | blue  
joe | green  
tom | red  
mike | yellow  
mike | green  
mike | red
```

How do I write SQL to generate the following?

### name | color | percent

```
joe | red | 66.6%
tom | blue | 50%
joe | green | 33.3%
tom | red | 50%
mike | yellow | 33.3%
mike | green | 33.3%
mike | red | 33.3%
```

Here is the code i was trying in microsoft access SQL

```
select name, color, (count(color)*100.0/count(*)) as 'perc'
from mytable
group by name, color;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the total for each color to get the percent.  This requires joining in another value.  I think the following will work in Access:

```
select nc.name, nc.color, nc.cnt * 100 / n.cnt & '%'
from (select name, color, count(*) as cnt
      from mytable as t 
      group by name, color
     ) as nc inner join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from mytable as t
      group by name
     ) as n
     on nc.name = n.name;
```

Comment: Hey thanks Gordon, I tried googling but I figured this question was a little more tricky than the answers I found. How does access know what "nc" and "n" are?

Comment: @barker those are aliases, they can be assigned to tables or subqueries  and they help with readability and make it possible to differentiate when referencing the same table.  They are assigned after the `)` for the subqueries.